# Create price range fields (min and max) using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

after spending a lot time I need help here.

I am creating a template. Where I can use different form fields. Everything is working. I am getting value form all fields as expected.

But problem is when I have 2 input fields together in one component and pass this component to parent component and get the value. then save this value in object.

I hope its clear enough. Thank you in advance

---

```
class Parent extends Component {
  handlePriceMinMax(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    /* I cant set the right values here. 
    *  These values get overwritten with latest value. 
    *  Because I get value on keypress/onChange value */
    this.setState({
            priceRange: {
                min: event.target.value, 
                max: event.target.value
            }
        }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child onChange={this.handlePriceMinMax}/>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="number" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
            <input type="number" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: I think the code you provided doesn't really work. Is the code on the top correct?

Comment: ya code is correct and its only which create problem. rest I didn't uploaded.

Comment: OK, in any case. The problem probably is because you are using one class inside of which you store your data. So it is like one state for both inputs.

Comment: Can you show how do you access min/max values in `handlePriceMinMax`?

Comment: I just edited the code

Comment: @DmitrijsBalcers, thats biggest problem because I can really access them. Normally I do it with 'event.target.value'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/zr30923nrm

I think this should work.
So basically you need to tell to the `handlePriceMinMax` what value do you want to update.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { priceRange: { min: 0, max: 0 } };
  }
  handlePriceMinMax = (value, event) => {
    const priceRange = this.state.priceRange;
    priceRange[value] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ priceRange });
  };
  render() {
    return <Child onChange={this.handlePriceMinMax} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={this.minChange} />
        <input type="number" onChange={this.maxChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  minChange = e => {
    this.props.onChange("min", e);
  };

  maxChange = e => {
    this.props.onChange("max", e);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code, you can create function in child first that get target value and pass to props function

```
class Child extends Component {
  submitInput(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e)
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="number" onChange={(e) => this.submitInput(e)}/>
            <input type="number" onChange={(e) => this.submitInput(e)}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```